# Does Spell Secrets change how a spell looks and acts?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, unearthed-arcana

If a Lore Mastery wizard uses the Spell Secrets ability to change the damage type of a spell, does it change the way the spell looks and acts?

Examples:

- If I were to cast *burning hands* but change the damage to cold
  damage would it become a cone of ice and snow?
- Or if I cast *ice knife* as fire damage would the knife be made of
  flames?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Yes

If ya go and look a little bit further down the [Unearthed Arcana](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_wizrd_wrlck_uav2_i48nf.pdf) that is the source of the Lore Mastery Wizard, you'll get this little tidbit.

> While the Spell Secrets feature offers increased versatility, at  the table   its effects can be  difficult   to  spot
> by  the other   players.    If  you’re  playing a   savant, **take  a
> moment  to  describe    how you alter   your    spells.**   Think   of
> a   signature   change  your    character   is  particularly    proud
> of. Be  inventive,  and make    the game    more    fun for
> everyone    by  playing up  the sudden, unexpected  tricks your character   can employ.
>
> For    example,    a   fireball transformed    to  require a   Strength    save    might   become  a sphere    of  burning rock    that    shatters    and slams   into    its target. A   charm   person that requires    a   Constitution    save might  take    the form    of  a   vaporous    narcotic    that    alters the  target’s    mood.

It doesn't specifically address changing damage types, but it encourages you to be creative with the descriptions, and emphasize the differences you have wrought in your spells through this feature.

Additionally, from a 'common sense' approach...a Fireball that does Ice damage should look like an ice blast, not a fire blast.

Spell Secrets should absolutely change the appearance of spells.

Comment: Disclaimer: Lore Mastery wizard is OP as heck. :D